# Format method failure

Tags: excel, vba

If I put this string as input to method `format`:
`"07/11/2009 00:33:22`" with format: `"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"` then as a result I get:
`2009-07-11 00:33:22`.

Why month is swapped with day? How to fix it?

Comment: Are ALL of the date/times stored as strings? Have *some* of them been converted to true dates? If you're aware of what the original value *should* be, has 11-Jul-2009 been misinterpreted as 07-Nov-2009 (or vise-versa)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually month and day are not swapped in your output, but it's the formatting of your input what is misleading. Try `=month("07/11/2009 00:33:22")` in a cell to see what is really month and day in your original data.

If your input is from a range, stored as data, then it's really 11th of July.

If your input is a string from any source, then look for the regional settings of your pc (control panel) to change default settings.

### Update

To ensure your text is converted to date the same way regardless your regional settings use this formula:
`=date(mid(A1,7,4),mid(A1,4,2),mid(A1,1,2)) + time(mid(A1,12,2),mid(A1,15,2),mid(A1,18,2))`

Comment: looking at rest of cells data, i have for example: 15/11/2014 18:59:00 and so on. So first one is day. Month in example you provided returns #VALUE!

Comment: so you have range of cells! please post sample data to help understanding your situation. please check also what is the number format of your cells, and also could be useful to post what is the default number formatting of your pc (control panels - region and language)

Comment: when i changed my regional settings to France, then date was created correctly. This is really confusing why excel is creating date according to regional settings instead of format passed :/

Comment: @JosiP: It's still not about how excel format dates, it format then correctly! It's about how it recognizes them, most probably your dates in the original location are stored as string, excel try it's best to convert them real dates, and it's best guess is to use the format defined in your regional settings.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are inputting the 7th of November 2009:

```
Format: "yyyy/dd/mm hh:mm:ss"
```

This will give you 2009/07/11 etc.

EDIT: Since someone is downvoting without any explanation, and since OP now seems to have decided on the order of input:

Assuming input 11th of July 2009:

```
Format: "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
```

This will give you 2009/07/11 etc.

Setting custom formatting to a cell, a selection of cells or an entire row or column will override regional settings. If this doesn't work, it's probably because the formatting isn't being forced to update.

Once you've applied the formatting, select the affected range or rows/columns, go to the Data tab, and click "Text To Columns". Unselect any optional checkboxes and follow the rest of the wizard. The formatting will now update across all selected cells.